# Another approach for long SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query whose purpose is to retrieve the records according to search parameters. Other parameters are fine but there's one field called "Member". When users put a part of name to that "Member" text box, it should return all the records in which that "Member" has been involved in different roles. I had quite a complex query but it was fine and only took a second before the where clause is put. My previous where clause was like

```
WHERE (( C.IDNumber LIKE '%11%' AND  C.OriginalIDNumber LIKE '%11%' 
AND  H.UserDisplayName  LIKE '%david%' OR C.SubmittedBy LIKE '%david%' 
OR J.UserID IN( Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR L.UserID IN( Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR X.DepartmentHead IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR E.DepartmentHead IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR N.UserID IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR O.UserID IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR Y.OrganisationAdmin IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR Y.FinalApprovalAuthority IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR Y.OrganisationFinance IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%') 
OR Z.UserID IN (Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%'))) 
AND (C.Status<>'Draft')
```

J,L,X,E and so on are different tables that I must join. I took more than a minute and I modifed it into

```
WHERE (( C.IDNumber LIKE '%11%' AND  C.OriginalIDNumber LIKE '%11%' 
AND  H.UserDisplayName  LIKE '%david%' OR C.SubmittedBy LIKE '%david%' OR W.UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%' 
OR AA.UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%' OR BB.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' OR CC.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' 
OR DD.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' OR EE.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' OR FF.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' 
OR GG.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' OR HH.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%' OR II.UserDisplayName LIKE  '%david%')) 
AND (C.Status<>'Draft')
```

by putting left outer join for User_Profile table with J,L,X,E and so on. AA, BB, CC and so on are new User_Profile tables to be joined.

But it is still taking 30 seconds which leads the "Timeout Expired" error when I run the application. Any other approach to reduce the time taking by query?

I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Comment: Please include the relevant database information (e.g. *which* RDBMS?) as well as any relevant *execution plans* and *indexes*. I prefer to use JOINS vs sub-queries here -- and while they both *could* be optimized to the same plan, this will vary based on RDMBs. Since `Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%'` is *highly repeated* and thus should likely be eliminated to a single join (again, this *could* be optimized out by the query optimizer (depends on RDMBS and optimizations!), but there is no reason for such duplication in the query!).

Comment: Also, the fact that all the tables have a `UserDisplayName` sounds like incorrect/insufficient normalization :)

Comment: Yes, Since Select UserID from USER_PROFILE where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%' is repeated, I changed it. It couldn't be solved by single join because once you join the User_Profile table with another table, it becomes limited. The only way I've found so far is to left outer join the User_Profile table with each & every table that need to be joined.


UserDisplayName is for display purpose only and it's only from User_Profile table not from others.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MS SQL? Starting from 2005 you can use CTE's (common table expressions) - first you select all possible IDs into CTE and then join to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTEs to avoid duplication of code:

```
WITH IdWeLikeToCheck AS
( Select UserID 
  from USER_PROFILE 
   where UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%'
)

....
WHERE ( ( C.IDNumber LIKE '%11%' AND  C.OriginalIDNumber LIKE '%11%' 
AND  H.UserDisplayName LIKE '%david%' OR C.SubmittedBy LIKE '%david%' 

OR J.UserID IN IdWeLikeToCheck 
OR L.UserID IN IdWeLikeToCheck 
OR X.DepartmentHead IN IdWeLikeToCheck  
OR E.DepartmentHead IN IdWeLikeToCheck  
... 
OR Z.UserID IN IdWeLikeToCheck )) 
AND (C.Status<>'Draft')
```

---

For someone to look at the timeout error, you'll have to provide the full query, the tables' definitions  and the execution plan.

Comment: @rahularyansharma: What limits do you mean?

Comment: i mean to say recurssion limit

Comment: Ah yes. But this CTE is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have queries with '%xxx%' wildcards on the end (actually in the front, in the back is fine), your indexes will be disregarded for those tables. Any wildcard at the beginning cannot be resolved using an index.

And fields like IDNumber hopefully are really numbers, so wildcards don't make much sense; and comparing a numeric field value with a string (or vice versa) will also mess up your use of indexes.

I imagine it's consequently reading every record in every table in the query, sometimes more than once.

Comment: Though IDNumber is number, the user want to search with "11211" to get all the records where IDNumbers will be like "1121122", "1121123" "2211211". That's why wildcard is required.

Comment: Do it is not a number. Point. ID codes are chars with a pattern (only 0-9), but not numbers. They should also not be mapped as numbers.

Comment: Yap, Yap. I mistyped. These are chars, not numbers. But it should be searched with wildcard, anyway.